# Can differential equation with integration factor be solved on another way?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$mx''+rx'=-g$

Is it possible to find $x'$ without using integration factor? Is there any other way, and if yes which one?

Comment: First of all, note that the substitution $x'=y$ leads to $my'+ry=-g$, a differential equation containing only the first derivate.

Comment: the $x'$ means derivative with respect to $r$? Or is the derivative with respect to, for example, $t$ and $r$ is some constant?